# knockoutjs data manipulation after update in view model issue

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

I have a master viewModel with two VMs and it is created via mapping plugin.

```
viewModelObj    = {
    first           : new firstVM(),
    second          : new secondVM()
}

viewModel = mapping.fromJS(viewModelObj, mappingOptions);
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

Data looks like this:

```
'firstObj'      : {
    'title'         : 'CURRENT title goes here',
    'children'      : [
        { 'id': '00001', 'name': 'Rube no 1' },
        { 'id': '00002', 'name': 'Rube no 2' },
        { 'id': '00003', 'name': 'Rube no 3' }
    ],
    'warning'   : false
},
'secondObj'     : {
    'title'         : 'Second Item title'
}
```

firstVM has observableArray children

```
self.children = ko.observableArray(item.children);

self.calLength = ko.computed(function() {
  return 'Total ' + self.children().length;
});
```

Everything seems to work fine until I update data. Updated data:

```
'firstObj'  : {
    'title'     : 'UPDATED TITLE goes here',
    'children'  : [
        { 'id': '00004', 'name': 'Rube no 4' },
        { 'id': '00005', 'name': 'Rube no 5' },
        { 'id': '00006', 'name': 'Rube no 6' },
        { 'id': '00007', 'name': 'Rube no 7' },
        { 'id': '00008', 'name': 'Rube no 8' },
        { 'id': '00009', 'name': 'Rube no 9' }
    ],
    'warning'   : true
},
'secondObj'     : {
    'title'         : '2nd Title UPDATED'
}
```

In html first.children().length returns correct length of updated array, foreach.children also works fine, but **calLength() function in VM doesn't return updated length. WHY?**

It looks like all data updated successfully, but can't be accessed in VM function if it is an array ( i can easily get self.title() or other observable data ). Maybe there are some problems with mappingOptions?

```
'first' : {
    create : function(options) {
        return  mapping.fromJS(options.data, {}, this);
    }
},
'second' : {
    create : function(options) {
        return  mapping.fromJS(options.data, {}, this);
    }
}
```

Here is a full demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/simoncereska/bfvgT/

p.s. If you have any other comments, you are welcome to post them :)

Thank You very much.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your children observable array is being updated with new values, and not replaced with a new observable array.